# Extracting Data from one Excel Workbook to another using 2 criteria

Tags: excel

I have two documents. Main one contains a table with IDs (rows) and Dates (columns), the complementary document contains the same: IDs (rows) and Dates (columns), but with filled data for each ID on each Date.

How can I check, whether ID + Date combination is present in the complementary document and transfer the  value to the main document?

I tried INDEX+MATCH and VLOOKUP functions, but I keep getting N/As in the main document

Thanks a lot

edit 1: These are two formulas I have tried:

```
=INDEX('[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$B$4:$AD$82;MATCH(C4;'[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$C$5:$C$82;0);MATCH(H2;'[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$S$4:$AD$4;0))

=VLOOKUP(C4;'[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$B$4:$AD$82;MATCH(H2;'[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$S$4:$AD$4;0);0)
```

Comment: can you [edit] the post to include the formula you tried.

Comment: is the target workbook open?

Comment: They are both open, yes

Comment: `[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$C$5:$C$82` should be `'[comp.xlsx]ACT CY'!$C$4:$C$82` to match the INDEX rows.  With the dates, make sure they are both dates or both strings that look like dates.  Same thing with IDs they should both be numeric or strings.  If there is a mismatch of type, it will not match.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a 2 step process:

1. CONCATENATE the ID+date in each file and VLOOKUP against that to understand which combination is present
2. If it does not give you an #N/A, meaning that it's present in both workbooks, then you can do a separate VLOOKUP (based on the concatenate) to bring in the columns you want.

Comment: The problem is, ID and Date are on two different Axis, and I need to check values on the ID by ID basis. If I understood you correctly